# I get error when I type conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, three.js, onclick, conditional-statements

I'm newbie with JavaScript and
I tryed to store the Vector position and whith two buttons (forward and backward) to move the Camera to that specific position. Also I tried to use 'gsap' to have soft movements but the code don't work.

```
//Coordinates
let positionIndex = 0;
const positions = [
    {
        x: -0.05,
        y: 0.6,
        z: -0.17
    },

    {
        x: -2,
        y: 1,
        z: 1
    },

    {
        x: 0.3,
        y: 0.6,
        z: -0.6
    }
]

//on buttonforward clicked
var element = document.querySelector(".button-1");
element.onclick = function MoveUp(){

if(positionIndex) == 3
{
    positionIndex = 0;
}
else
{
    positionIndex += 1;
}}

camera.position.x = positions[positionIndex].x
camera.position.y = positions[positionIndex].y
camera.position.z = positions[positionIndex].z


//on buttonbackwards clicked
var element = document.querySelector(".button-2");
element.onclick = function MoveDown(){

if(positionIndex) == 0
{
    positionIndex = 3;
} 
else 
{
    positionIndex -= 1;
}}
camera.position.x = positions[positionIndex].x
camera.position.y = positions[positionIndex].y
camera.position.z = positions[positionIndex].z
```

Someone can give me advice?

Thank you.

Comment: On click you're only changing `positionIndex`, nothing less, nothing more.  Instead of changing the `camera.position.x/y/z` on CLICK, you're changing them once, on *init*. My best suggestion is to learn how and when to use functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: you have syntax errors in your code. `if(positionIndex) == 3` should be `if(positionIndex == 3)`

Comment: Also, open Developer Tools Console, and learn how to use `console.log()` or `debugger` to test your values, or see any potential errors in your code. I.e: `if(positionIndex) == 0` should be (as Robin pointed out) `if(positionIndex === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

when you set positionIndex to 3 you will get undefined. Perhaps it would be better to use `positions.length - 1`